# print words between two particular words in a given string

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

if one particular word does not end with another particular word, leave it. here is my string:

```
x = 'john got shot dead. john with his .... ? , john got killed or died in 1990. john with his wife dead or died'
```

i want to print and count all words between `john` and `dead or death or died.`
if `john` does not end with any of the `died or dead or death` words. leave it. start again with john word.

my code :

```
x = re.sub(r'[^\w]', ' ', x)  # removed all dots, commas, special symbols

for i in re.findall(r'(?<=john)' + '(.*?)' + '(?=dead|died|death)', x):
    print i
    print len([word for word in i.split()])
```

my output:

```
 got shot 
2
 with his          john got killed or 
6
 with his wife 
3
```

output which i want:

```
got shot
2
got killed or
3
with his wife
3
```

i don't know where i am doing mistake. 
it is just a sample input. i have to check with 20,000 inputs at a time.

Comment: your point is not clear. Since `with his          john got killed or` comes after the word john it counts as 6?

Comment: @MarlonAbeykoon `john with his .... ? , john got killed or died`  the 1st `john` word is not ending  with `dead or death or died`. start with 2nd `john` word. the output i want is `got killed or` not  `with his john got killed or`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead regex:

```
>>> for i in re.findall(r'(?<=john)(?:(?!john).)*?(?=dead|died|death)', x):
...     print i.strip()
...     print len([word for word in i.split()])
...

got shot
2
got killed or
3
with his wife
3
```

Instead of your `.*?` this regex is using `(?:(?!john).)*?` which will lazily match 0 or more of any characters only when `john` is not present in this match.

I also suggest using word boundaries to make it match complete words:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=\bjohn\b)(?:(?!\bjohn\b).)*?(?=\b(?:dead|died|death)\b)', x)
```

[**Code Demo**](http://ideone.com/5TlGf9)

Comment: Far mor elegant than my solution, take this one.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you want to start over, when there is another `john` following in your string before `dead|died|death` occur.

Then, you can split your string by the word `john` and start matching on the resulting parts afterwards:

```
x = 'john got shot dead. john with his .... ? , john got killed or died in 1990. john with his wife dead or died'
x = re.sub('\W+', ' ', re.sub('[^\w ]', '', x)).strip()
for e in x.split('john'):
    m = re.match('(.+?)(dead|died|death)', e)
    if m:
        print(m.group(1))
        print(len(m.group(1).split()))
```

yields:

```
 got shot 
2
 got killed or 
3
 with his wife 
3
```

Also, note that after the replacements I propose here (before splitting and matching), the string looks like this:

```
john got shot dead john with his john got killed or died in 1990 john with his wife dead or died
```

I.e., there are no multiple whitespaces left in a sequence. You manage this by splitting by a whitespace later, but I feel this is a bit cleaner.

Comment: Nice solution, but it won't work for the part up until the first John. Add a [1:] slicing and it should be fine :)

Comment: Right, if there sentence starts with `... dead john` (i.e. something before the first `john`, that contains one of the three stop words), it would also treat it as a match. I'll fix that.